# Grid pagination not working when use group clause in collection

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, collection-filtering, grid

I m working on product grid but its pagination or product count not working(as it display wrong count). as my block _preparecollection function is as below.i have added category filter code in collection so i have to use group clause to prevent error for same id already exist.

```
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $store = $this->_getStore();
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('attribute_set_id')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('type_id')
            ->joinField('category_id',
                'catalog/category_product',
                'category_id',
                'product_id=entity_id',
                null,
                'left');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => array(4,10)))
            ->distinct(true);
            $collection->getSelect()->group('e.entity_id');


        if (Mage::helper('catalog')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_CatalogInventory')) {
            $collection->joinField('qty',
                'cataloginventory/stock_item',
                'qty',
                'product_id=entity_id',
                '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                'left');
        }
        $collection->joinField('position',
                'catalog/category_product',
                'position',
                'product_id=entity_id',
                null,
                'left');
        $collection->joinField('websites',
            'catalog/product_website',
            'website_id',
            'product_id=entity_id',
            null,
            'left');
        if ($store->getId()) {
            //$collection->setStoreId($store->getId());
            $adminStore = Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID;
            $collection->addStoreFilter($store);
            $collection->joinAttribute(
                'name',
                'catalog_product/name',
                'entity_id',
                null,
                'inner',
                $adminStore
            );

            $collection->joinAttribute(
                'custom_name',
                'catalog_product/name',
                'entity_id',
                null,
                'inner',
                $store->getId()
            );
            $collection->joinAttribute(
                'status',
                'catalog_product/status',
                'entity_id',
                null,
                'inner',
                $store->getId()
            );
            $collection->joinAttribute(
                'visibility',
                'catalog_product/visibility',
                'entity_id',
                null,
                'inner',
                $store->getId()
            );
            $collection->joinAttribute(
                'price',
                'catalog_product/price',
                'entity_id',
                null,
                'left',
                $store->getId()
            );
        }
        else {
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect('price');
            $collection->joinAttribute('status', 'catalog_product/status', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');
            $collection->joinAttribute('visibility', 'catalog_product/visibility', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');
        }

        $this->setCollection($collection);

        parent::_prepareCollection();
        $this->getCollection()->addWebsiteNamesToResult();
        return $this;
    }
```

I had google and got answer and add it to `lib/varian/data/collection/db.php`

```
    public function getSelectCountSql()
{
     $this->_renderFilters();

        $countSelect = clone $this->getSelect();
        $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
        $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_COUNT);
        $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_OFFSET);
        $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);

        if(count($this->getSelect()->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP)) > 0) {
            $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP);
            $countSelect->distinct(true);
            $group = $this->getSelect()->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP);
            $countSelect->columns("COUNT(DISTINCT ".implode(", ", $group).")");
        } else {
            $countSelect->columns('COUNT(*)');
        }
        return $countSelect;
}
```

[image]
But no luck please help to resolve this

Comment: What class are you extending? `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid` ?

Comment: Yes i extending `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid`

Comment: What query returns call to the getSelectCountSql ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Collections and Lazy Loading in Magento

The reason pagination does not work is because of how collections are counted and how lazy loading works with collections.

Collections in Magento implement the class `Countable`.  Due to lazy loading of collections in Magento, whenever the method `count()` is called, the data has to be loaded.  As a workaround of this, collections implement a method called `getSize()`.  It will clone your SQL statement, wrap it in a `COUNT()` and return the result.  This allowed a collection to get a total count without loading all the data.  This allows for things such as filters to be added at the last minute.

This is what `Varien_Data_Collection_Db::getSize()` and it's partner `getSelectCountSql()` looks like:

```
/**
     * Get collection size
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getSize()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_totalRecords)) {
            $sql = $this->getSelectCountSql();
            $this->_totalRecords = $this->getConnection()->fetchOne($sql, $this->_bindParams);
        }
        return intval($this->_totalRecords);
    }

    /**
     * Get SQL for get record count
     *
     * @return Varien_Db_Select
     */
    public function getSelectCountSql()
    {
        $this->_renderFilters();

        $countSelect = clone $this->getSelect();
        $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
        $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_COUNT);
        $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_OFFSET);
        $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);

        $countSelect->columns('COUNT(*)');

        return $countSelect;
    }
```

Basically, it drops limits, columns, ordering, etc and leaves the filters behind.  Then it adds a MySQL `COUNT()` to the columns.

### The Problem

Normally, on one table, this would return one row with the total count.  This is why `getSize()` does a `fetchOne()` against the query.  However, when doing things such as table joins, group bys, and the like, you will not return one row, you will return multiple.  It is because of this that you need to alter the `getSize()` method in your collection.

### The Solution

This is what your method should look like now:

```
public function getSize() {

        if ( is_null( $this->_totalRecords ) ) {
            $sql = $this->getSelectCountSql();
            // fetch all rows since it's a joined table and run a count against it.
            $this->_totalRecords = count( $this->getConnection()->fetchall( $sql, $this->_bindParams ) );
        }

        return intval( $this->_totalRecords );
    }
```

Instead of a `fetchOne()`, we ran a `fetchAll()` wrapped in a `count()` PHP function.  Now your totals will return appropriately.

Comment: This is how I wish all the answers on the SE was. A solution AND some depth.

Answer (score 5):

Great solution. Maybe someone has the same problem as we had, so I will post another possible solution.
In our case we had a collection, which sometimes included a group by statement and sometimes it didn't, depending on the grid where the collection was loaded. Using the solution above, we found two problems:

1. If the collection is empty, the size is valued as 1, although it should be zero.
2. In the cases where the getSize method was called without a group by statement on the collection, the size is valued as 1 no matter how many items are in the collection.

After debugging a while we found out, that in case 1 the part

```
$this->getConnection()->fetchall( $sql, $this->_bindParams )
```

returns an array which has one entry with value 0.
That is why the count function returns 1 although no entries were found.

In case 2 the same part returns an array with one entry, whose value is the real size of the collection. The count function again returns 1 and not the value.

Searching for an alternative, we found out, that the product collection uses a rewrite of the function getSelectCountSql().
We adapted this and changed it a bit, which ended in this solution:

```
public function getSelectCountSql()
{
    $countSelect = parent::getSelectCountSql();
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP);
    $countSelect->columns('COUNT(DISTINCT item_id)');

    return $countSelect;
}
```

It solves the two issues I already mentioned and as far as I can see, it also works for the other cases.

Comment: Thank you for giving the reference of product collection model. It helped me.